How to validate XML Request/Response against xsd schemas in postman?
How to validate XML Request/Response against XSD schemas in Postman?
For your information, I saw the solution if I install the xmllint-schema library in Postman, but I'm not sure how to do that.
Please help solve how to install the xmllint-schema library in Postman.
const xml = pm.request.body.toString(); // Get the XML request from the body

const xsdSchema = `
    <!-- Paste your XSD schema here -->
`;

const xmlSchema = require('xmllint-schema').XMLSchema;
const parser = new DOMParser();
const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, 'application/xml');
const xsdDoc = parser.parseFromString(xsdSchema, 'application/xml');
const schema = new xmlSchema(xsdDoc);
const isValid = schema.validate(xmlDoc);

if (isValid) {
    console.log('XML validation passed');
} else {
    console.error('XML validation failed');
}

Please provide your help solving how to install the xmllint-schema library in Postman.
